# Which expression is correct "Many eyes" or "a lot of eyes"?

Tags: grammar, countable-nouns

Which of the below expression is correct?

- Argos has many eyes.
- Argos has a lot of eyes.

Comment: Have you searched for information about the difference between 'many' and 'a lot of'?

Comment: Short answer - 'many' is more formal and is always OK; 'a lot of' is informatl and conversational.

Comment: Er, that's 'informal'.